# Dependency injection in partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`. We want to use partial classes to split the service implementation into multiple files. The code looks like this:

**IAccountsService.cs**

```cs
public interface IAccountsService
{
    AppUser Get(string username);
    bool HasRole(string username, int roleId);
    // ...
}
```

**AccountsService.cs**

```cs
public partial class AccountsService : IAccountsService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    
    public AccountsService(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    public AppUser Get(string username)
    {
        return _dbContext.AppUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
    }
}
```

**AccountsService.Roles.cs**

```cs
public partial class AccountsService : IAccountsService
{
    public bool HasRole(string username, int roleId)
    {
        // _dbContext is null here!
    }
}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```cs
private readonly IAccountsService _accountsService;

public AccountsController(IAccountsService accountsService)
{
    _accountsService = accountsService;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test1()
{
    // _dbContext is NOT null
    return Ok(_accountsService.Get("admin", 1));
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test2()
{
    // _dbContext is null
    return Ok(_accountsService.HasRole("admin", 1));
}
```

I observed that when I call `Test1` (which calls `Get(string username)`), `_dbContext` is NOT `null`. But, when I call `Test2` (which calls `HasRole(string username, int roleId)`), `_dbContext` is `null`. When calling `Test2`, constructor in `AccountsService.cs` is never hit.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it works OK if you put all the code in a single file instead? `partial` really shouldn't have any effect on DI.

Comment: Do you have multiple constructors in `AccountsService`? You should also add argument validation like this: `this.dbContext == dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));`.

Comment: `partial` is compile-time feature, DI is runtime. It can't affect each other.

Comment: @Dai Yes, indeed there were multiple constructors in `AccountsService`. I removed them and now it works.

Comment: "We want to use partial classes to split the service implementation into multiple files." Seems to me your classes are simply too big, which causes maintainability issues. Splitting them up into partials will only marginally help you. You might be violating the Single Responsibility Principle here. You might want to fix the underlying problem first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments noted: "`partial` is a compile-time feature, DI is a runtime." It is the compiler putting those two classes together, so if you see that `_dbContext` is null during the invocation of `HasRole`, it could mean a few things:

1. The `AccountsService(MyDbContext dbContext)` constructor is called with a `null` argument. As you say that the constructor is "never hit" in `Test2`, this options seems to be proven false.
2. There is a different constructor (e.g. a default ctor) that is called. This might be the case if you have third partial class that you're not aware of.
3. The two partials are not merged by the C# compiler to a single CLR type, which will happen if they both have a different namespace *or different assemblies*. In that case C# generates a default constructor for the "Roles" type, which will be called by the DI container.

Comment: I had a different constructor which was being called. Thank you for pointing it out.